# Issue with trying to prevent hover effect from being applied

Tags: html, css

So, in my application I have the following HTML that is generated from my React application, which uses components from 3rd party libraries:

```
<button class="bulk-action" disabled>
    <span class="bulk-action-icon">some icon here</span>
    Some text here
</button>
```

I am trying to configure the `span` so that it does not change colour when the button is hovered over. I need to override the default CSS that comes from this 3rd party library and that is currently being applied to the icon when the button is hovered over. When the `button` is hovered, over, the icon changes colour, and the CSS (when inspecting in Chrome) looks like the following (all from 3rd party library who provide the component):

```
.gmRHND .sc-ifAKCX:hover .sc-bwzfXH {
    color: red; // this is applied
}

.gmRHND .sc-bwzfXH {
    color: blue; // strikethrough in chrome, being overridden
}
```

And yet, even when I apply my own CSS such as the following, the strikethrough still applies

```
.bulk-action:disabled:hover .bulk-action-icon {
    color: initial; // `unset` also doesn't work
}
```

So, I need the `blue` to be applied without specifically declaring `color: blue` in the above CSS. Am I missing something? Any ideas?

Note: I've replaced the actual colour codes that are used with `red` and `blue` for simplicity

Comment: Have you tried using `!important` ?

Comment: @DeepDev Yes, and I can set `.bulk-action:disabled:hover .bulk-action-icon {    color: initial !important; }` and yet the `color: blue;` line is still not being applied.

Comment: Please add a code snippet to your question that replicates your issue.

Comment: Adding a code snippet to replicate the issue would require including a reference to the 3rd party library that provides the components, and I am unable to divulge the particulars of said 3rd party library for legal reasons. This is also the reason I changed the names of colours and class names.

Comment: _"and the CSS (when inspecting in Chrome) looks like the following"_ - unclear how that should even apply to the HTML you have shown - the classnames used in those CSS selectors, are nowhere to be found in that HTML ...?

Comment: Why not inherit instead of initial? Initial gives the default browser behaviour

Answer (score 0):

A simple !important keyword will probably solve your problem

```
.gmRHND .sc-bwzfXH {
    color: blue; !important
}
```

usually, third party codes don't use the !important keyword to let you have conrtol over your code a bit more even when using theirs. if this doesn't do the trick, you can try this:

```
<div class="sc-bwzfXH">
  <div class="new-class">
    your text
  </div>
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.new-class{
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: That CSS is coming from the 3rd party library that supplies the component, so I don't have a way of altering it directly. I mentioned this in my original post, but have edited it to make it clearer.

Comment: alright, I've just edited the answer, try it

Answer (score 0):

the names of classes seem to be random. you have to give a class to your controllable parent div that you have and then control your desire element.

for example :

```
<div className="myClass">
      <ComponentFromLibrary />
</div>
```

then in your CSS you have to find your desire element for example:

```
.myClass ...... button >span{
    //some styles
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can add a css rule to your styles, you can create a rule that has a bigger specificity of the rule already in place that sets the text-color of element where the mouse is hovering.

In this demo I show how you could create such a more specific rule. The specificity is given by how many selectors were used in this order: !important,inline,id,class,type. Now I don't expect this to be perfectly clear
but consider it a shallow hint on how rules get applied.

Anyway on a given style attribute, `!important` says that it should override that value whatever is the specificity of that rule. Of course collisions may arise if too many rules used `!important`.

```css
.specific-class-with-rules-already-inplace {
    background: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.specific-class-with-rules-already-inplace:hover {
    color: red;    
}

/*
here you are overriding the hover behaviour with a rule having more specificity
you could force higher specificity using !important after the style attribute value
but it's unneeded here
*/
.bulk-action .bulk-action-icon:hover {
    color: unset;
}
```

```html
<div class="bulk-action">
  <span class="bulk-action-icon specific-class-with-rules-already-inplace">Overrides</span>
</div>

<br/>

<span
  class="specific-class-with-rules-already-inplace">
  Element not overriding the rule
</span>
```